# Why does JSON.parse() throw Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token when trying to parse a simple json object?

Tags: javascript, json

The following two lines of javascript code cause the Uncaught SyntaxError:

```
    var testObj = JSON.parse('{ testFunc: function () { console.log("whoa there"); }}');

    testObj["testFunc"]();
```

I don't understand what is invalid about my json string.

Comment: http://jsonlint.org/ will tell you. What you have is simply not JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware, that is not a JSON string, but rather javascript held by a string literal. JSON is, just like XML, a means to represent data across multiple platforms. Please have a look at the specification for JSON:

http://www.json.org

If you want to pass values that are actually functions, you need to use the javascript `eval` method alternatively let JSON string values work as keys to an object that maintains these methods.

Answer (score 3):

JSON doesn't allow for inline function definitions... that's JavaScript.

http://json.org/